# minutia points extraction using crossing number in matlab

Tags: matlab, fingerprint

I am working on minutiae points (ending and bifurcation) extraction in fingerprint recognition for which I am using Crossing number. I have applied the following code in Matlab. In this code, I am applying color codes to ending and bifurcation so that we can see these points easily in the binary image.

Here CN is finding crossing number. I am using a 3*3 image window and finding crossing number only for the patch which has center value 1 in 3*3 image patch.

But I have found that it extracts false ending points. Also all bifurcation cannot be detected using this code. Can someone please suggest any changes or help me to find out the fault in the code.

Matlab Code:-

```
binary_image=im2bw(imread('input_1.tif'));
%% Skeleton
skel_image=~bwmorph(binary_image,'skel',Inf);
% figure;imtool(skel_image);title('Skeleton Image');

inv_skel_image = 1-skel_image;
figure;imtool(inv_skel_image);title('Inverse Skeleton Image');

test_inv_img = inv_skel_image;

%% crossing number
[r, c]=size(test_inv_img);

CN_Count = zeros(r,c);
CI = zeros(r, c, 3);
e = 1;
CN_4 = 0;
for i=2:r-1
    for j=2:c-1

        Sub_Image = test_inv_img(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1);

        if(Sub_Image(2,2) == 1)
            CN_Count(i,j) = sum(Sub_Image(:));
            CN = CN_Count(i,j);
            if CN == 1  % Isolated
                CI(i, j, 1) = 255; % white
                CI(i, j, 2) = 255;
                CI(i, j, 3) = 255;
            end
            if CN == 2  % Ending
                % find co-ordinates of ending
                Ending(e,1) = i;
                Ending(e,2) = j;
                e = e+1;
                CI(i, j, 2) = 255; % GREEN
            end
            if CN == 3  % Continue
                CI(i, j, 3) = 255; % BLUE

            end
            if CN == 4 % Bifurcation
                if((Sub_Image(2,1)==1) && (Sub_Image(1,3)==1) && (Sub_Image(3,3)==1))
                    CI(i, j, 1) = 255; %RED
                elseif((Sub_Image(1,2)==1) && (Sub_Image(3,1)==1) && (Sub_Image(3,3)==1))

                    CI(i, j, 1) = 255; %RED
                elseif((Sub_Image(1,1)==1) && (Sub_Image(1,3)==1) && (Sub_Image(2,3)==1))
                    CI(i, j, 1) = 255; %RED
                elseif((Sub_Image(1,1)==1) && (Sub_Image(1,3)==1) && (Sub_Image(3,2)==1))
                    CI(i, j, 1) = 255; %RED
                else
                    CN_4 = CN_4 + 1;
                end
            end

            if CN == 5 % CROSSING
                CI(i, j, 1) = 255; %pink
                CI(i, j, 2) = 255;
                CI(i, j, 3) = 0;
            end

        end
    end
end
imtool(CI, []);

%% to find coordinates using color codes
% All 3 planes values
R_Plane=CI(:,:,1);
G_Plane=CI(:,:,2);
B_Plane=CI(:,:,3);

% [j1,j2]=find(Mask_End);

% find co-ordinates of Ending using color codes
Mask_End = (R_Plane==0) & (G_Plane==255) & (B_Plane==0);
[Ending1(:,1),Ending1(:,2)]=find(Mask_End);

% find co-ordinates of Bifurcation using color codes
Mask_Bif = (R_Plane==255) & (G_Plane==0) & (B_Plane==0);
[Bif1(:,1),Bif1(:,2)]=find(Mask_Bif);
```